# Angular ui calendar, $scope.events remains as undefined

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

here's what my controllers looks like

```
    var resource = Restangular.all('api/events/');
        resource.getList().then(function(events){
             $scope.events = events;

       });


$scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) {
    element.attr({'tooltip': event.title,
                  'tooltip-append-to-body': true});
    $compile(element)($scope);
};
/* config object */
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar:{
    height: 700,
    editable: true,
    header: {
       left: 'prev,next title',
            //center: 'title',
       right: 'month,agendaWeek,'
    },
    eventRender: $scope.eventRender
  }
};

/* event sources array*/
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

i think angular ui calendar directive is getting triggered first,
how can i make it to get data first and then trigger directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a function in `eventSources` which does the fetching like so, you have to call the `callback` function with an array of events.

```
var resource = Restangular.all('api/events/');

/* event sources array*/
$scope.eventSources = [fetchEvents];

function fetchEvents(start, end, timezone, callback) {
  resource.getList()
    .then(function(events) {
      // do some event processing ?
      callback(events);
    });
}
```

---

Side note from my own experience with fullCalendar and Angular:

```
$scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) {
  element.attr({'tooltip': event.title, 'tooltip-append-to-body': true});
  $compile(element)($scope);
};
```

This is a really big bottleneck on performance, and you probably want to avoid this. It will create a dom node+logic for EVERY event you render, which can be quite a lot. The best thing to do is to either make your own tooltip directive which reuses the same dom element or to use the `title` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the tooltip, i'll use my own tooltip directive.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it should work

```
/* config object */
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar:{
    height: 700,
    editable: true,
    header: {
       left: 'prev,next title',
            //center: 'title',
       right: 'month,agendaWeek,'
    },
    eventRender: getEvents
  }
};

$scope.eventSources = [];

function getEvents(callback){
        console.log(from);  // For test purposes

        // Request for data from server and when it comes, call callback to update calendar
          var resource = Restangular.all('api/events/');
        resource.getList().then(function(events){
             $scope.events = events;
             callback(events);

       });
    }



};
```